# AWS SAM Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid when adding day of week

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sam

I am making a CloudWatch event and I need it to run every Friday at 11pm UTC. I attempted to turn this on by doing `cron(0 23 * * FRI *)` which according to all documentation I could find, is perfectly correct syntax. However it was failing every time I tried to deploy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue was that if you set a day of the week specifically, then you can not set the third parameter to `*` it needs to be set to `?`. This makes logic sense because the third parameter is `Day of Month` and so you can't have it run every day of the month AND every Friday. Updating to 
`cron(0 23 ? * FRI *)` solved the problem for me.

An important and I suppose obvious note when setting cron values: Think about how each value affects the other values you've set. Does each one make logical sense in conjunction with the others?